# Is there a way to disable (or at least clear) Find/Replace history in SublimeText 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

SublimeText keeps Find / Replace history. Is there an easy way to disable or at least clear this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find/replace history is stored in a Session file.

Mac location:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session
```

PC location:

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime-session
```

The Session file hold tons of information and settings (over 3000 lines in my file), including the find/replace history. Like everything else in Sublime Text, it's JSON formatted, so you could just write a simple script to go in a delete the information stored there.

The find history itself is located under

```
Session.sublime-settings->settings->new_window_settings->find_state->find_history
```

`replace_history` is also located in the same spot.

Comment: @orokusaki In that case, your options are more limited, because there does not seem to be an option for clearing the history built in. 1) close the program, delete the history, and restart. 2) deal with having a history, because you can't do anything about it.

Comment: This doesn't work, since Sublime Text somehow repopulates the file with the old data as soon as you close the program. Clearing the items from your project's `sublime-workspace` also doesn't address the issue.

Comment: Thanks Darrick - I'm giving up on this, before I burn too many cycles (i.e., option 2).

Answer (score 0):

I am using ST3 and I can just delete the contents (Select all -> Delete) in the Find results tab and close it. The next search only gives the results of the new find.

Comment: The question is not about clearing Find results. It is about clearing the Find keywords history that is stored by the editor. Next time you go to find, it will show the previously searched key words.